# Flutter how to show phone number from contact_service plugin

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service  to show phone contact number and name

I have done with a name but the issue is I can't find the parameter for the phone number

My code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';

class ContactsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ContactsPageState createState() => _ContactsPageState();
}

class _ContactsPageState extends State<ContactsPage> {
  Iterable<Contact> _contacts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getContacts();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> getContacts() async {
    //Make sure we already have permissions for contacts when we get to this
    //page, so we can just retrieve it
    final Iterable<Contact> contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();
    setState(() {
      _contacts = contacts;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    double Height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double Width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: (Text('Contacts')),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: Height * 0.07,
            width: Width * 0.9,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
            ),
            child: Center(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Naya Customer Add karein',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular',
                          color: Colors.blueAccent),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
          ),
          _contacts != null

              ? Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: _contacts?.length ?? 0,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                Contact contact = _contacts?.elementAt(index);
                return ListTile(
                  contentPadding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2, horizontal: 18),
                  leading: (contact.avatar != null && contact.avatar.isNotEmpty)
                      ? CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: MemoryImage(contact.avatar),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  )
                      : CircleAvatar(
                    child: Text(contact.initials()),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  title: Text(contact.displayName ?? ''),
                  subtitle: Text('+92 33237812'),
                  //This can be further expanded to showing contacts detail
                  // onPressed().
                );
            },
          ),
              )
              : Center(child: const CircularProgressIndicator())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can see here its successfully showing name of contact but I need to know how can I show number of that contact ?

Comment: add your Contact model class too.

Comment: @ahmadbajwa i have no model for Contact

Comment: OK create a model class: Contact Model

// Name
String displayName, givenName, middleName, prefix, suffix, familyName;

// Company
String company, jobTitle;

// Email addresses
Iterable<Item> emails = [];

// Phone numbers
Iterable<Item> phones = [];

// Post addresses
Iterable<PostalAddress> postalAddresses = [];

// Contact avatar/thumbnail
Uint8List avatar;